# What does it mean when we say a function depends continuously on something?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $X$ is a normed space, $x$ some point in $X$, and $Y$ its finite-dimensional subspace, then to find a $y^*$ in $Y$ such that $\inf_{y} \|x-y\|=\|x -y^*\|$, we choose a basis $(e_j)$ for $Y$ and approximate $x$ by a linear combination $\sum \alpha_je_j$. Then it is said that $$f(\alpha)=\|x- \sum \alpha_j e_j\|$$

depends continuously on $\alpha_j$'s. What does this mean, and how do you prove this? Here $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \dots \alpha_n)$.

Comment: [This](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~siva/ma41707/ode91.pdf) provides a description of continuous dependence. (pdf warning)

Answer (score 1):

You can prove continuous dependence using the reverse triangle inequality and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for sums:
\begin{align}
     |f(\alpha)-f(\beta)| & = |\,\|x-\sum_{j}\alpha_j e_j\|-\|x-\sum_{j}\beta_j e_j\|\,| \\
  & \le \|(x-\sum_j \alpha_j e_j)-(x-\sum_j \beta_j e_j)\| \\
  &  = \| \sum_j (\beta_j-\alpha_j) e_j \| \\
  &  \le \sum_j |\beta_j-\alpha_j| \|e_j \| \\
  &  \le \left(\sum_{j}\|e_j\|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{j}|\beta_j-\alpha_j|^2
\right)^{1/2} \\
  &   = M \|\alpha-\beta\|_{\mathbb{C}^n}.
\end{align}
Here, $\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{C}^n}$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$.